# Can I pass an integer value for checkbox in html from php?

Tags: php, html

I have this code in my laravel blade.

```
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value=$check name="is_featured" checked="checked"/>
  <?php
    if(isset($_POST['is_featured'])){
    $check = 0;
    }else{
    $check = 1;
    }
  ?>
```

I know it doesn't work, but I want to know if there is a way that I can manipulate the value with if else in php then return it to value in html. Thank you very much.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. You are defining `$check` **after** you read it. Normally, dynamically setting the value of a checkbox based on user input doesn't do anything useful, and you'd want to set the `checked` attribute instead.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"
       value="<?php echo $check; ?>" name="is_featured"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
    $check = isset($_POST['is_featured']) ? 1 : 0;

    var_dump($check);
?>
```

Change the action of the `form` to match your script name.